# Error Occured while listing consumable product in openerp

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I want to list products in a select box but I need to show only consumable products.

I can list all product by using

```
 _columns = {
                'product_id':fields.many2one('product.product','Name',required=True)

   }
```

I tried to list the consumable product using

```
_columns = {
                'product_id':fields.many2one('product.product','Name',required=True,domain=[('product_template.type','=','consu')]),
```

But it is not working . I tried the domain expression like this because 'product_template' model contain the product type and the relation field between 'product_product' model and 'product_template' model is 'id'. So how can I write domain expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also apply the domain on record from the xml(view side), like

```
   <field name="product_id" domain="[('type','=','consu')]"/>
```

Try this it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
'product_id':fields.many2one('product.product','Name',required=True,domain=[('type','=','consu')]),
```